# Cannot use AnimatedVectorDrawable inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, vector-graphics, animatedvectordrawable

I am trying to run an animated vector inside a fragment. First, I tried passing a drawable resource to fragment and then setting it as a background and starting the AnimatedVectorDrawable object created from the background. It only showed a static background with no animation. Alternatively, I set the background resource in the fragment's layout resource and then creating an AnimatedVectorDrawable from the background in the fragment code and start the AVD. Again, the result was the same: No animation.

I also tried passing the animation to the UI thread to run (just in case fragments use a different thread). Again, no success.

According to [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable), as of API 25, vector animations run on RenderThread. I am not sure if it has something with my failure to start the animation inside the fragment.

My code for the fragment is as follows:

```
class AvdFragment : Fragment() {
    /**
     * AVD resource file passed to this fragment to be animated
     */
    private var mAvdResource: Int = 0;

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_avd, container, false)
    }


    override fun setArguments(args: Bundle?) {
        super.setArguments(args)
        mAvdResource = args!!.getInt(AVD_RES)
    }

    private val LOG_TAG = javaClass.name

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)



            val root = activity!!.findViewById<ViewGroup>(R.id.fragment_root)

            root.setBackgroundResource(mAvdResource)

            val avd = root.background as AnimatedVectorDrawable

            avd.start()




    }

    companion object {
        val AVD_RES = "avd_resource"
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using `setArguments(...)` from elsewhere?

Comment: @StanislavBondar I call it from MainActivity